# How to modify router and viewsets for template rendering

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a simply CRUD application with Rest-Framework
my **views**, **serializers** and **routers** is created dynamically.

I used a simple code from DRF docs like that:
**VIEWS:**

```
class PersonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
```

**SERIALIZERS:**

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = Person
       fields = '__all__'
```

**URL:**

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'persons', PersonViewSet)
```

Now I have to do smth for displaying data for end-users.

My goal is:
1. Play 1-2 weeks with build-in django functionality for frontend development
2. Consider about vue.js as a frontend framework.

So I have to use django and DRF as a backend (this is for sure).
I have some trouble with template rendering.

Now I create a simple HTML templates and try to implement them.
There are some problems when using them with ViewSets. Seems that I have to use another parent class for views.
Could you provide me some examples how should I change my views and router?
I already tried to use simply APIView, but seems that routers works only with viewsets.

Comment: Should I create several views - one for API, others for rendering HTML? Is there are some common approaches for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I create a simple HTML templates and try to implement them. There are some problems when using them with ViewSets. Seems that I have to use another parent class for views.

**Views**

DRF defaults to rendering responses as either JSON (`rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer`) or BrowsableApi (`rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer`). [[source](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#setting-the-renderers)]

In order to render HTML from within DRF `APIView` (and it's subclasses) you have to set `TemplateHTMLRenderer` as one of `renderer_classes` in your class: [[source](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#templatehtmlrenderer)]

```py
class PersonDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return Response({'person': self.object}, template_name='person_detail.html')
```

**Routers** only work with `ViewSets`. To expose your custom view on an endpoint you have to append it into `urlpatterns` in your urls file: [[source](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#using-include-with-routers)]

```py
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'persons', PersonViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^person_detail/$', PersonDetail.as_view()),
]

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

Comment: Oh, this seems to be helpful!
So I have to define views for API and another views for user interface?

Comment: Not necessarily. For ex. using custom query (`GET: /persons/?output=html`) and handling it properly in your view, you can return anything you want from it (`renderer_classes` accepts multiple objects and higher order functions decide which one to use based on content type returned from the view - Response body).
In my projects I follow a pattern of separating user interface views from API views.