# how to apply template for django ModelViewset class

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

hello i am stuck and i can't apply my html to this class please help

```
class ProductViewSet(ModelViewSet): 
    queryset = Product.objects.prefetch_related('images').all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter, OrderingFilter]
    filterset_class = ProductFilter
    pagination_class = DefaultPagination
    permission_classes = [IsAdminOrReadOnly]
    search_fields = ['title', 'description']
    ordering_fields = ['unit_price', 'last_update']
```

Comment: Look at the answer for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57143258/how-to-modify-router-and-viewsets-for-template-rendering .. you should just have to add that custom `get` method

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Use `filterset_backends` instead of `filter_backends`

Comment: it is very helpful, but in my situation how i can add include the filteset_backends and other fields in my html because it is not objects @Nealium